# Unique Columns in SQL Views

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, view

In my database I have one table that contains a complete list of products, and another table that contains the same list of products on the x-axis, with a list of customers on the y-axis, where the value for each product can be 1 or 0 depending on whether that customer can view that product.  My SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT products.product_code, products.product_type, products.product_category, products.product_title, products.product_description
FROM product_lists
INNER JOIN products
ON product_lists.product_code=products.product_code
WHERE product_lists.customer="1"
ORDER BY products.product_code
```

My problem is that I would like to create a view of this result for each customer to use as that customers product table, however when I create it I get the message "This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available." even though the product_code field is set as a primary key in both the products table and the product_lists table.

How can I create a join/view that uses the primary key from the table(s) it was created from?  In short I would like the product_code field to become the primary key of my view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the `join`.  You can fix this by moving the condition to the `where` clause.  MySQL doesn't allow subqueries in the `from`, but it does in the `where`:

```
SELECT p.product_code, p.product_type, p.product_category, p.product_title, p.product_description
FROM products p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM product_lists pl
              WHERE pl.product_code = p.product_code AND
                    pl.customer = 1
             )
ORDER BY p.product_code;
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I need, but I don't understand the "FROM products p", or "FROM product_lists pl" parts of this query...  I assume this is similar to an alias command so that you can refer to products as "p" and product_lists as "pl"?  But when I try this query it says "Unknown column 'p.product_code' in 'field list'" - and if I replace p with product_code then I would end up with "FROM products products" which of course doesn't work...

Comment: Now I've done a bit of reading on subqueries I understand it - the join wasn't necessary. Thanks

Comment: @user3640967 . . . You have the expression `products.product_code` in your `select`; `p.product_code` refers to the same column here, just using an alias.  When defining aliases, the `as` is optional and even undesirable in the `from` clause.

Comment: Although I still get " #1054 - Unknown column 'p.product_code' in 'field list'" when I try to use your query...

Comment: @user3640967 . . . According to your question, `products.product_code` is a field in the table.  I don't know why you would get that error.

Comment: products.product_code IS a field in my database, but still getting this error!  I've just written it out long hand though and it works fine now.